# Delete File Used By Other Process

Tags: c#, wpf, process

I am trying to create a C# app which loads a powerpoint and makes each slide a JPG that is stored in a list of BitmapImages. The user should be able to load another powerpoint, which, on load, deletes each of the other JPGs in the folder. Currently, I am unable to delete the JPGs, as they are "being used by another process" which happens to be this app. How can I work around this?

```
foreach (ISlide slide in presentation.Slides)
{
             System.IO.Stream imageStream = slide.ConvertToImage(Syncfusion.Drawing.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
             System.Drawing.Image convertedImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(imageStream);

             if (!System.IO.File.Exists(picsPath + "\\Slide_" + slide.SlideNumber + ".jpg"))
                  convertedImage.Save(picsPath + "\\Slide_" + slide.SlideNumber + ".jpg");
             else
             {
                        try
                        {
                  System.IO.File.Delete(picsPath + "\\Slide_" + slide.SlideNumber + ".jpg");               
                  convertedImage.Save(picsPath + "\\Slide_" + slide.SlideNumber + ".jpg");
             }
                  catch (Exception df){Console.WriteLine(df.StackTrace);}
             }
             bitmap = new BitmapImage();
             bitmap.BeginInit();
             bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(picsPath + "\\Slide_" + slide.SlideNumber + ".jpg");
             bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
             bitmap.EndInit();
             VisualAidPPT.Add(bitmap);
             convertedImage = null;
}
```

Comment: THat is because jpg file is being locked by the previous operation you performed on it. Use .Dispose() to release file handler

Comment: You can use `handle.exe` from sysinternals which gives you the process that uses the specified file. You can parse its output and kill that process then you can delete your file.

Comment: Why are you using `System.Drawing.Image.FromStream` (which is WinForms) instead of directly loading a BitmapImage by assigning the `imageStream` to its `StreamSource` property? There doesn't seem to be any need to save the JPEG files at all.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Now, when I display a new ppt, the first few slides are still displayed from the last ppt that was loaded, but the last few are from the new updated one. Checking the files in the folder, all of them are the new updated ones. Would anyone know why this may be?

Comment: @Clemens I have used the StreamSource property, but an exception is thrown when I don't have the UriSource set to the location of the file

Comment: You don't need to set UriSource when you set StreamSource (and you don't need a file!). But you may have to set `imageStream.Position = 0;` before. Which exception is thrown? We can't read your mind.

Comment: @Clemens I get a System.NotSupportedException: The component cannot be found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write any image file at all.

Just directly use the Stream returned by `slide.ConvertToImage` to load a BitmapImage:

```
foreach (var slide in presentation.Slides)
{
    var bitmap = new BitmapImage();

    using (var imageStream = slide.ConvertToImage(Syncfusion.Drawing.ImageFormat.Jpeg))
    {
        imageStream.Position = 0;

        bitmap.BeginInit();
        bitmap.StreamSource = imageStream;
        bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmap.EndInit();
    }

    VisualAidPPT.Add(bitmap);
}
```

---

EDIT: In case the above does not work, you may still decode a `System.Drawing.Image` and save that to a MemoryStream:

```
foreach (var slide in presentation.Slides)
{
    var bitmap = new BitmapImage();

    using (var imageStream = slide.ConvertToImage(Syncfusion.Drawing.ImageFormat.Jpeg))
    using (var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(imageStream))
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;

        bitmap.BeginInit();
        bitmap.StreamSource = memoryStream;
        bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmap.EndInit();
    }

    VisualAidPPT.Add(bitmap);
}
```

Comment: I am getting an exception System.NotSupportedException: No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found

Comment: Did you set `Position = 0`?

Comment: See the edited answer. It copies the image stream to a MemoryStream before loading the BitmapImage.

Comment: Still get the same exception; the component cannot be found

Comment: Can you try a different format than `Syncfusion.Drawing.ImageFormat.Jpeg`? E.g. PNG?

Comment: Still the same using Syncfusion.Drawing.ImageFormat.Png

Comment: That's odd. If you can create a System.Drawing.Image from the stream, save that to a file and load a BitmapImage from the file, you should of course also be able to create a BitmapImage directly from the stream. Anything else doesn't make sense...

Comment: Yes it's very strange. The exception is thrown at bitmap.EndInit()

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what happens when the stream does not contain a complete JPEG frame

Comment: Just for a test, try to keep the image stream open as shown in the second code part above.

Comment: Still the same exception after removing cacheoption

Comment: I've made another edit, now with using `System.Drawing.Image`. If that still doesn't work, I don't know what else to try.

Comment: Now i get a System.FileFormatException: The image cannot be decoded. The image header might be corrupted.

Comment: That's from `System.Drawing.Image.FromStream`? How did that work in your original code?

Comment: It worked when I made the file format System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp, thank you for all of your help, I'll accept your answer